# Id not passing when hyperlined on image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Id not passing when a hyperlink is created in the image whereas when it is replaced by text it does, below is the example code and this is an angular js app

Working:

```
shtml = '<a target="_blank" class="dlink" href="javascript:;" id="' + data + '">Dlink</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
```

Not Working:

```
shtml = '<a target="_blank" class="dlink" href="javascript:;" id="' + data + '"><img src="/imgs/s/3.png" title="3" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
```

The javascript is being called from a view file(js).

Please help me on this

Comment: This is very unclear.  IDs don't usually pass anywhere, so "Id not passing" is meaningless.  What do you mean by "working"?

Comment: Can you try using `data-ng-attr-id="' + data + '"` instead of your `id="' + data + '"`

Comment: @Tibrogargan ID is not queried in another js file when the hyperlink is given to the image whereas if there was text it is, hope i'm clear

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa it's not working

Comment: Is your `data` a **$scope** variable then ? to which a data is fed using an ajax call ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa so the "data" is "id" coming from elasticsearch and passing through the datatables and when the user click on the image they should get a popup by querying that id from mongodb, so the mondob query is in another ".js" file

Comment: Hmm. in both the cases can you tell us looking at the **browser inspector** to see what the value of `id` is rendered onto the DOM ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa here it is <a target="_blank" class="dlink" href="javascript:;" id="54fded1d07bc3783c4887365"><img src="/imgs/s/3.png" title="3" /></a>

Comment: Ok so the ID is getting rendered ... is that value right ? If not what should be the right value ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa yes that's correct it's rendering but when doing req.val at backend it's not passing

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so the issue seems to be in your controller the way you pass the ID value to the backend. so how are you passing the ID value from the view to the backend ? I can't see any 'req' variable.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa using like this - exports.srch= function(req , res){- And querying it on mongodb via req.query.val

Comment: I mean the value from the ID of the `<a>` tag you mentioned in the example. where is that taken from in the controller ?